# Binary Search Tree : Insertion Wrong Answer

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to write binary search insert method but it gives the wrong answer. I couldn't find what is the reason. Here's my code:

```
public static Node insert(Node root,int data) {
    Node  insertedNode =  new Node(data);
            
    if(root == null){
        root=insertedNode;
    }
    else {
        Node node = root;
        Node  insertedNode =  new Node(data);
        
        while(root.left !=null && root.right !=null){
            if(root.left.data>data){
                root=root.left;
             }
             else {
                root=root.right;
             }
        }
         
        if (data > root.data) {
            root.left = insertedNode;    
        } 
        else {
            root.right=insertedNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while` loop is where your problem starts. Think about how the `while` loop will execute against a sample input.

Comment: You say you get a wrong answer on input. What is that answer?

Comment: I am solving it  on hacker rank  i just simply return the head node of tree. I just want to know  is there any mistake concerning the  logic of the algorithm.

Comment: As @Yousaf said, try to play with your mind or paper, some sample input. First input: 10, it becomes root. Second input 5, it becomes root.left. Third input 3, it removes 5 and adds itself as root.left in place of 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is very easy to detect. Look at your `while`:

```
    while(root.left !=null && root.right !=null){
        if(root.left.data>data){
            root=root.left;
         }
         else {
            root=root.right;
         }
    }
```

It will only seek to deeper levels if both left and right of root exists. So, let's suppose you try to add 2, 3, 4. You insert 2, which will become your root. Then, you try to add 3. Your while detects that it's not true that both of left and right of root are not null. So, it will add 3 to the right. So far, so good:

```
2
  \
     3
```

Now, you try to add 4. Your while checks whether root.left and root.right are not null. It's false, so it will be the right of the root, resulting in

```
2
  \
     4
```

instead of

```
2
  \
     3
       \
         4
```

Let's fix your while:

```
while((root != null) && (((root.data < data) && (root.left != null)) || ((root.data > data) && (root.right != null)))){
    if(root.left.data>data){
        root=root.left;
     }
     else {
        root=root.right;
     }
}
```